# JavaScript's Array,Scriptlet combination is not working

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts

I wrote following piece of code to retrieve value of 'recipientList' in array abc but it is not working. Whenever I use

```
alert(abc[i]);
```

It returns 'undefined'.
I need to use this abc[i]'s value as 'options[]' index in

document.getElementById("recipients").options[i].selected

What am I doing wrong?

```
var abc;

    <logic:greaterThan value="0" property="ConfigId" name="ConfigForm">
    <%

    ArrayList<RecipientDTO> recipientList= (ArrayList<RecipientDTO>) request.getAttribute("recipientTypesList");
    if (recipientList != null && recipientList.size() > 0) 
    {
            for (int i=0; i < recipientList.size(); i++) 
             {
                RecipientDTO recipientType = (RecipientDTO) recipientList.get(i);%>
                abc = [<%=recipientType.getRecipientType().toString()%>];
    <%  } %> 

    var i;      
    for(i=0;i<abc.length;i++) {

        document.getElementById("recipients").options[i].selected = true; 

    }       

<% }
    %>
    </logic:greaterThan>
```

I also used

```
var abc = new Array();
abc[i] = "<%=recipientType.getRecipientType().toString()%>";
```

instead of

```
var abc;
abc = [<%=recipientType.getRecipientType().toString()%>];
```

but no use :(

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing `var abc` with `var abc=new Array()` and

```
abc = [<%=recipientType.getRecipientType().toString()%>];
```

with

```
abc[<%=i%>] = '<%=recipientType.getRecipientType().toString()%>';
```

Comment: your answer was a great help .. really thankful , and feeling also dumb that i had been making such a stupid mistake writing abc[i] instead of abc[<%=i%>] :$